# Does ({∅}) = {∅}?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to disprove that (A<sub>1</sub> ∩ A<sub>2</sub>) = (A<sub>1</sub>) ∩ (A<sub>2</sub>). 

Do I have this right?

Suppose A<sub>1</sub> = {-1}, A<sub>2</sub> = {1}, (x) = x<sup>2</sup>. 

Then A<sub>1</sub> ∩ A<sub>2</sub> = {∅}, and (A<sub>1</sub> ∩ A<sub>2</sub>) = {∅}.

But (A<sub>1</sub>) = (-1) = 1, and (A<sub>2</sub>) = (1)=1, so (A<sub>1</sub>) ∩ (A<sub>2</sub>) = {1}.

Thus, (A<sub>1</sub> ∩ A<sub>2</sub>) ≠ (A<sub>1</sub>) ∩ (A<sub>2</sub>) because {∅} ≠ {1}.

Comment: Your basic idea is right, but you are confusing $\emptyset$ with $\{\emptyset\}.$

Comment: I suggest you use Mathjax to format your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong in $A_1 \cap A_2 = \{\emptyset\}$ and $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = \{\emptyset\}$. It should be $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$ and $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = \emptyset$.

Be careful with your notation!

$A_1,A_2$ are sets and so are $f(A_1), f(A_2)$. As a result, $f(A_1) = f(A_2) = \{1\}$.

To remove such ambiguity, we can write $f[A_1]$ and $f[A_2]$ instead of $f(A_1),f(A_2)$.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose {∅} is a set containing the empty set then?
I also don't quite understand how square braces remove any ambiguity...

Comment: @JonahM Suppose our function is $f: A \to B$. Then you mostly always mean $A_1 \in A$ when writing $f(A_1)$. But $A_1 \subseteq A$ and generally $A_1 \not \in A$, and $f(A_1) := \{f(a) \mid a \in A_1\}$. To be more precise, we should write $f[A_1] := \{f(a) \mid a \in A_1\}$.

Comment: @JonahM In regards to your first question, $\emptyset$ has $0$ elements, whereas $\{\emptyset\}$ has one element.